# debug assertion failed vc\include\vector vector iterator + offset out of range in chamferMatching Opencv

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am stuck with the problem while implementing chamfer matching program in OpenCV

https:// code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/chamfer.cpp?rev=4194

Following is the code it is reading 
template image

[image: http://img593.imageshack.us/img593/6391/5klx.png]

and test image
[image: http://img5.imageshack.us/img5/6619/u76z.png]

, I am using VS 2008 and OpenCV2.4.6

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{    
    IplImage *src;
    src = cvLoadImage("C:\\Users\\JOSHI\\Desktop\\Images\\logo_in_clutter.png",1);      
    Mat img=cvarrToMat(src);  
    imshow("Mat",img); 

    src = cvLoadImage("C:\\Users\\JOSHI\\Desktop\\Images\\logo.png",1);  
    Mat tpl=cvarrToMat(src);  
    imshow("Mat",tpl); 
    Mat cimg;

    // if the image and the template are not edge maps but normal grayscale images,
    // you might want to uncomment the lines below to produce the maps. You can also
    // run Sobel instead of Canny.    
     Canny(img, img, 5, 50, 3);
     Canny(tpl, tpl, 5, 50, 3);    
    vector<vector<Point> > results;
    vector<float> costs;
    int best = chamerMatching( img, tpl, results, costs );
    if( best < 0 )
    {
        cout << "not found;\n";
        return 0;
    }    
    size_t i, n = results[best].size();
    for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        Point pt = results[best][i];
        if( pt.inside(Rect(0, 0, cimg.cols, cimg.rows)) )
           cimg.at<Vec3b>(pt) = Vec3b(0, 255, 0);
    }
    imshow("result", cimg);

    waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

this is the error image 
[image: http:// img138.imageshack.us/img138/7339/m1d.png]

can you suggest me why I am getting this error as I am new to OpenCV and Image Processing

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. Solution: http://code.opencv.org/issues/3603
You need to download opencv from source, open the chamfermatching.cpp and comment line:

```
~Matching()
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i<templates.size(); i++) {
        //delete templates[i];
    }
}
```

Then you need to rebuild opencv. After this it should work.