# How to get chamerMatching to work on OSX?

Tags: xcode, macos, opencv, computer-vision, malloc

I'm trying to use OpenCV's chamferMatching functionality to work on OSX, but getting an error about a failed attempt at freeing objects that weren't allocated (as far as I can tell):

```
fs(58697,0x100b3c000) malloc: *** error for object 0x103800000: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

I found few helpful posts like this two:

1. [chamerMatching malloc error](http://answers.opencv.org/question/28360/chamermatching-malloc-error/)
2. [debug assertion failed vc\include\vector vector iterator + offset out of range in chamferMatching Opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19182083/debug-assertion-failed-vc-include-vector-vector-iterator-offset-out-of-range-i/23733981#23733981)

On Ubuntu, simply compiling [OpenCV 2.4.1](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/releases?after=2.4.4) from source and using that did the trick.

The same did not work on OSX though. I also commented out the templates deletion in the `Matching` destructor:

```
~Matching()
        {
            for (size_t i = 0; i<templates.size(); i++) {
                // delete templates[i];
            }
        }
```

but no joy.

I even tried commenting out ALL the delete statements in chamfermatching.cpp, but I still get the same error.

**Update** I've tried recompiling OpenCV 2.4.1 with 3 different versions of g++: 4.9, 5 and 6, but I'm getting linking errors. Here's an example compiling with g++ 5:

```
g++-5 ../fs.cpp -I/Users/George/Downloads/Grouped/cv/opencv-2.4.1/build/install/include/opencv -I/Users/George/Downloads/Grouped/cv/opencv-2.4.1/build/install/include -L/Users/George/Downloads/Grouped/cv/opencv-2.4.1/build/install/lib -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_core -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_gpu -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_ml -lopencv_nonfree -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_photo -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_video -lopencv_videostab -o fs
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::chamerMatching(cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point_<int>, std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > >, std::allocator<std::vector<cv::Point_<int>, std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > > > >&, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >&, double, int, double, int, int, int, double, double, double, double)", referenced from:
      _main in ccTJvcHd.o
  "std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > cv::CommandLineParser::analyzeValue<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool)", referenced from:
      std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > cv::CommandLineParser::get<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool) in ccTJvcHd.o
  "cv::CommandLineParser::has(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > cv::CommandLineParser::get<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool) in ccTJvcHd.o
  "cv::CommandLineParser::getString(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > cv::CommandLineParser::get<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool) in ccTJvcHd.o
  "cv::imread(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)", referenced from:
      _main in ccTJvcHd.o
  "cv::imshow(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, cv::_InputArray const&)", referenced from:
      _main in ccTJvcHd.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've tried adding flags like `-std=c++11` then `-std=c++0x`, but no joy.

Any tips on how I could get over this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although hacky, one option worked on OSX (even with OpenCV 2.4.13): removing the compiled .dylib and adding the uncompiled contrib module to the project.

For OpenCV 2.4.1 there it was just a matter of commenting out delete statement.
For OpenCV 2.4.13 I also had to comment out two cvconfig.h includes.