# Matching path in terrain

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, geometry, gis

I need to match a path recorded by [lidar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lidar) (x/y/height) onto a map tile (pixel height field)

I can assume the problem is 2.5D (ie a unique height for each point, no caverns) and the region is small enough that the grid is uniform (don't need to consider curvature). Naturally the track data is noisy and I don't have any known locations in advance.

Rather than do a full 3D point based Iterative Closest Point are there any simple algorithms for purely surface path matching I should take a look at ?

Specifically it seems to be an image processing problem(x,y,height=intensity) so some sort of snake matching algorithm?

Comment: I don't know what an ICP is, but wouldn't you just want to adjust each path point onto the map model triangle that's closest? If the map is a grid in x-y, it's trivial. If not then you just need a nearest point retrieval struct, say a kd-tree. Or you could saerch over a Delaunay triangulation.

Comment: Do you know the scale or does this need to be optimized, too?

Comment: So you have a series of sequential points (x,y,z) and you want to find the best location for those on a raster consisting of tiles in the x-y plane associated with average heights for those tiles?

Comment: @Richard, pretty much. I want the actual map coords for the path in the xyz data. Basic iterative matching problem - just wondering if there were any approaches i hadn't thought of

Comment: Not that I can think of, at least.

Comment: The solution would be a (dx, dy) which has to be added to the points in the path to get the minimal sum of squared height differences between the corresponding tile height for a point and its actual height? Or can there also be scaling factors?

Comment: Do you already have the path as part of the map tile (maybe one of many ?) if so, one option might be be to build a metric for existing path (relative change in direction from one point to another for example) to find one path most similar in curvature to your recorded path, then compute the difference in scale to size-up. the thing that sticks out as "in common" is height. even if the scales don't match, the profile/relative differences of the path and existing map: this actually sounds like your iterative closest point.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of brute force (calculate error for full path from each starting point) you can only expand the best points and potentially save a lot of work.

1. Normalize:

   - Subtract (pathMinX, pathMinY) from all points in the path.
   - Subtract (gridMinX, gridMinY) from all points in the grid.
2. Find pathMaxX, pathMaxY, gridMaxX, gridMaxY.
3. deltaMaxX = gridMaxX - pathMaxX, deltaMaxY = gridMaxY - pathMaxY.
4. Create an array or list  with (deltaMaxX + 1) * (deltaMaxY + 1) nodes for all the combinations of deltaX and deltaY. Each node has to hold the following information:

   - index, initialize with 0
   - deltaX and deltaY, initialize with the loop counters
   - error, initialize with (path[0].height - grid[path[0].x + deltaX][path[0].y + deltaY].height)^2
5. Sort the array by error.
6. While arr[0].error <= arr[1].error:

   - arr[0].index++
   - if arr[0].index == n: return (arr[0].deltaX, arr[0].deltaY)
   - arr[0].error += (path[arr[0].index].height - grid[path[arr[0].index].x + arr[0].deltaX][path[arr[0].index].y + arr[0].deltaY].height)^2
7. Remove node 0 and insert it at the correct position, so that the array becomes sorted again.
8. Repeat step 6. and 7. until a solution was returned.

You can (should, I think it's worth it) further improve the algorithm if you first sort the points in the path by extreme heights (lowest and highest points first and then moving towards the average height in regard to the grid, e.g. sort by abs(height - averageGridHeight) descending). Like this large errors are produced early and therefore branches can be cut a lot earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Purely, theoretical, but what if you encode the 3D data as grayscale images (3D path as grayscale image, height map is already something like that probably, just need to ensure scales make sense).

If you have the 3D path as a grayscale image and the height map as a grayscale image perhaps you could do a needle in haystack search using computer vision techniques. For example in, OpenCV there are a couple of techniques for finding a subimage in a larger image:

1. [Template Matching](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html) - (overly simplified) uses a sliding window doing pixel comparison
2. [Chamfer Matching](https://github.com/kipr/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/chamfer.cpp) - making more use of edges - probably more suitable for your goal. bare in mind I [ran into an allocation bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43288875/how-to-get-chamermatching-to-work-on-osx) last time using this: it does work in the end, but needs a bit of love (doing malloc fixes and keeping track of the cost to get read of false positives) but there are options to handle the scale difference

Template matching examples:
[image: template matching]
[image: template matching python api]

Chamfer matching example:
[image: chamfer matching]